# Javascript TypeError: Cannot read property when nested inside a window.onload function

Tags: javascript

**SOLVED:** Will move to close post but for future reference here is what happened. The children div in the parent div I was referencing were dependent on an AJAX call. So I set an interval to keep checking if the element existed with...

```
var checkExist = setInterval(function() {
   if ($('parent').length) {
      // do work on child elements
      clearInterval(checkExist);
   }
}, 100);
```

**ORIGINAL POST BELOW**

I am getting into writing some scripts to make testing tasks simple. I need to wait to run some of these until the page is fully loaded. Naturally I nest my code in ...

```
window.onload = function () { code in here }
```

So I am trying to store an element in a var that I know exists and I know works without being nested in onload. The var is written like this.

```
var element = document.getElementById('userPanel').getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
```

I can run this in console and it returns the element I need. When I run my script nested in the onload function. It throws a type error. Is there some fundamental principle of javascript I am overlooking here? Thanks!

For sake of clarity here is the whole code section glued together

```
    window.onload = function () {
var element = document.getElementById('userPanel').getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
}
```

Comment: Please provide all the relevant code including the HTML.

Comment: Are you _sure_ the `userPanel` element exists on page load? Is it possible that it's inserted by another function that runs on load, or later?

Comment: FYI a better (more efficient) way to get your element would be: `var element = document.querySelector("#userPanel div");`

Comment: @duskwuff I am positive. It works sometimes and then sometimes it doesn't. It's behaving like a race condition is present but I just don't see how

Comment: You must provide us with enough code to be able to reproduce the issue or we can't help you.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Thanks! I'm a bit a of a hack together type of guy but I will use this moving forward. To select the first div in #userPanel would I just do document.querySelector("#userPanel div")[0]; ??

Comment: @Murph_Fish You don't need the `[0]`. `document.querySelector` returns the first matching element; if you want an array of all matches, use `document.querySelectorAll`.

Comment: The only possible reason for this error is that the `userPanel` element doesn't exist when the page is finished loading. So it must be getting added asynchronously, not as part of the HTML. Since it's asynchronous, you run into this race condition where it sometimes works and sometimes fails.

Comment: @barmar Is there a way I can wait for that element to exist, asynchronous makes a lot of sense now.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: Will move to close post but for future reference here is what happened. The children div in the parent div I was referencing were dependent on an AJAX call. So I set an interval to keep checking if the element existed with...

```
var checkExist = setInterval(function() {
   if ($('parent').length) {
      // do work on child elements
      clearInterval(checkExist);
   }
}, 100);
```